# How to count distinct values in a MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, count, distinct

I would like to count distinct values in a MongoDB which are between certain dates.

Something like the following in SQL:

```sql
select distinct(count(iid)) 
from collection
Where date > 2015-04-03 and date < 2015-04-04
```

I have been running successfully the following query on the MongoDB, however, this returns the total count (not the count of distinct values):

```js
db.m_2015_04.find(
{ "_timestamp" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2015-04-03T00:00:000Z"), "$lt" : ISODate("2015-04-03T23:59:000Z") }})
.count()
```

Comment: unfortunately ,this result with an error.

Answer (score 3):

what about following ?

```
db.m_2015_04.distinct('iid', { "_timestamp" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2015-04-03T00:00:000Z"), "$lt" : ISODate("2015-04-03T23:59:000Z") }}).length
```

Comment: just be aware that distinct will not work if the distinct values exceed 16 MBytes.  in this case you got to use aggregation framework or a map reduce job.